# Can't link subscription to Azure B2C

Tags: azure, azureportal, azure-ad-b2c, azure-subscription

I was trying to get rid of old tenants and cleaning up my subscriptions but it looks like now it is even worse...

I have a Default tenant with a Pay-As-You-Go subscription.
I have 2 other tenants ("tenant_1" and "tenant_2"), in which I try to have different B2C directories (for different projects).
Under my Default tenant, I created 2 resource groups, lets call it "resource_1" and "resource_2" where I intend to have my B2C directories and, in the future, other services I might have for each project.

I see 2 different issues:
Issue 1:
Now, when I go to "tenant_1" (which already had a b2c directory before), I can see the warning "An Azure subscription is required...", however, when I follow the steps

> Switch Directories to the location of your target Azure subscription
> Under Marketplace, search for and select 'B2C'
> Select Create to link this B2C Tenant to a subscription

I can't find the existing B2C
If I try to create a subscription for this tenant, it fails and tells me that I should do it in the default one (which already has it)

Issue 2:
from "tenant_2" I can't really do anything, can't create resources, can't see my b2c, etc.
In this case, when I go to my default tenant and select the resource group, I can see there is a b2C tenant, click there and I get redirected to the incorrect b2c tenant (to the default one instead of the one in the resource group).

I know this sounds crazy, and very complicated, I can't really understand what is going on, but I spent all day trying to figure this out and there seems to make no sense at all...

Maybe the understanding I have about tenants, resource groups and directories is wrong... but this all seems very convoluted and unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: [Link an Azure AD B2C tenant to a subscription](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/active-directory-b2c/billing#link-an-azure-ad-b2c-tenant-to-a-subscription)

Comment: [Azure B2C link to Azure subscription](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/58949/azure-b2c-link-to-azure-subscription.html), [Help adding B2C tenant to subscription](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/512934/help-adding-b2c-tenant-to-subscription.html) and [Broken Experience For Linking B2C to Account](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/15452)